# How do you fix an input device that simply doesn't work?

Tags: recording, sound-devices, audio-interfaces

I've been using a Zoom H4n as an audio interface for a while - and it was working fine until I upgraded to Windows 8. Now, the only input I get is the occasional jolt of sound, several seconds after I played anything - basically it doesn't work at all.

I've tried specific solutions but it's not a software issue because it occurs in no matter the program (Skype, Reaper, Windows Recording Devices), and there's nothing to find on the Zoom (they don't have a support site), so:

Could anyone share what you did to fix a misbehaving recording device like this? I'm sure I could try some general solutions, for example driver issues, bitrate mismatches, that sort of thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First I'd connect this device to another computer that is not running Windows 8 and see if the same thing is happening there. If it is then you know there's something wrong with the device or rather it's unlikely that it's the computer/OS.

If it's not acting up then it is most likely the computer/OS that's at fault.

If it's a software problem my next step under Windows would be to check for new drivers (if any) and while waiting for those to install get Zoom's service on the phone.

Should that not resolve the issue, and you specifically mention this happened after upgrading to Windows 8, I would simply downgrade back to Windows 7 and keep an eye out for solutions down the line.

Ideally someone else on this board will have an H4n and Windows 8 around and might be able to help you better.

By the way out of pure curiosity you said you 'could try general solutions', why haven't you?

Cheers

Comment: Definitely - general solutions should be the first port of call. Drivers, checking bit rate, etc - do all these first as they are simplest.